# Leaflet click on map and retrieve address

Tags: leaflet, reverse-geocoding

I'm working on a Leaflet map based upon https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/reverse-geocoding.html. Depending the place you click on the map you'll obtain the real address (street, city, area) or the commercial name: on the linked example, zoom max the map then click on any restaurant and you'll get "Royal Bangladesh Indian Restaurant" instead of address...
To avoid this I'm trying to detect first if the address is a real one or not:

```
  map.on('click', function (e) {

    geocodeService.reverse().latlng(e.latlng).run(function (error, result) {
      if (error) {  return; }

      let address = result.address.Match_addr;
          lat = parseFloat(e.latlng.lat);
          lon = parseFloat(e.latlng.lng);

      getAddress(address,lat,lon);

    });  

 });   

 function getAddress(addr,lat,lon) {

     let ad = addr.split(',');

     if(typeof ad[1] == "string") { // OK -> real address

        alert(ad[0]+', '+ad[2]+' '+ad[1]+'');
        //   street      city     zip code     ----> works perfectly

     }

     else if(typeof ad[1] == "undefined") { // commercial name

        // ...now what I'm tying to achieve: fire pseudo-click with new coords on map

        morelat = lat+0.00005;
        morelon = lon+0.00005;

        map.fire('click',[morelat,morelon]) // <--- doesn't work but looking for something like

     }

 }
```

The idea is to increase/decrease lat+lon by mixing morelat, morelon (and later lesslat, lesslon), turning around the inital click place till I can find the closest real address.

I've tried to do this but it doesn't work

```
     else if(typeof ad[1] == "undefined") { // commercial name

        morelat = lat+0.00005;
        morelon = lon+0.00005;

        geocodeService.reverse().latlng([morelat,morelon]).run(function (error, result) {
            if (error) { return; }
            getAddress(addr,morelat,morelon)
        });

     }
```

Any idea of the best way to proceed?

Comment: OK : real address is in longLabel JSON...

Answer (score 1):

OK, it seems to be easy:

result.address.LongLabel is the full address including commercial name in first position if provided.

result.address.Match_addr is the commercial name if provided, else the real address if not.

The LongLabel.length (in my tests) is 6 (real address) or 7 (with commercial)

```
      map.on('click', function (e) {

          geocodeService.reverse().latlng(e.latlng).run(function (error, result) {
              if (error) {  return; }
              let elems = result.address.LongLabel.split(',')
              if(elems.length==6) {
                address = result.address.LongLabel;
              }
              if(elems.length==7) {
                // remove commercial name
                address = result.address.LongLabel.replace(result.address.Match_addr+',','');
              }
              let ad = address.split(',');
              alert(ad[0]+', '+ad[2]+' '+ad[1]+'');
          });  

      });
```

Comment: It seems to be avalaible for France. To be tested for other countries/address systems.